# Edge cases in the Fibbonacci Sequence

Tags: c++, math, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

This is my first stack overflow question. I will attempt to provide a thorough description of my problem and ask specific questions.

I am doing a programming task on an online judge that requires me to return the nth term of the fibonacci sequence mod m, where m is an integer such that 1 ≤ M ≤ 300000. This is the code I have so far.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

map<long long, long long> memo;
long long m;
long long f;
int fib(long long n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        if (i <= 2) {
            memo[0] = 0;
            memo[1] = 1;
            memo[2] = 1;
        } else {
            f = memo[i - 1] + memo[i - 2];
            memo[i] = f;
        }
    }
    return memo[n];
}

int main(void) {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    long long n;
    cin >> n >> m;

    if (m == 1) {
        cout << 0 << '\n';
    } else {
        cout << abs(fib(n) % m) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the specific doubts I have.

1. Why does n mod m sometimes produce negative results and what does it mean
2. Is simply doing `abs(fib(n) % m)` the solution to this problem
3. Is there any other edge case that I am not able to see here.

Also I just wanted to say that I am aware that it is not good practice to use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std` but it is fast and easy for competitive programming purposes. If you have spotted any other miscellanious points which I can use to improve please let me know, thanks.

Comment: You're overflowing - the 30000:th FIbonacci number has approximately 200000 binary digits, and you only have 63. When the answer is supposed to be modulo some `m`, it is always a hint that intermediate results will overflow unless you're aware of the identities `(a + b) % m == (a % m + b % m) % m` and `(a * b) % m == (a % m * b % m) % m`.

Comment: If your only stated goal is to return the `nth` number, why do you need a map to record every number that gets calculated up to that? That makes no sense. Oh, and by the way, if you attempt to calculate it straightforwardly, it won't work, for some obvious reasons. Like all silly puzzles on those useless online competition sites that nobody really cares about, you need to know a particular mathematical trick to solve the puzzle. There's a mathematical trick in making this calculation, and this has nothing to do with C++. If you don't know what the trick is, you will not be able to solve it.

Comment: I am not aware of any country that requires someone to waste time on codechef, or something similar, in order to get a scholarship.

Comment: Also, you only need to store the last two numbers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Introduicing Singapore. Where everything has to be done competitively..

Comment: Is that some kind of a law, there? Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

```
            f = memo[i - 1] + memo[i - 2];
```

may cause overflow.

You should do

```
            f = (memo[i - 1] + memo[i - 2]) % m;
```

or

```
            f = memo[i - 1] + memo[i - 2];
            while (f >= m) f -= m;
```

instead.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand the second trick that you have used

Comment: Also for the first trick thend doesnt that mean that the following statement f = memo[i] will become incorrect

Comment: @pnkasdhith my catchphrase is: Do the maths first. This covers all you need: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation. Look for "distributive" for the relation you need to apply here

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the math

Comment: Like I said at first, it's a math trick. You'll spend a lot of time figuring out what is the math trick here. Unfortunately, those silly puzzles on competitive coding sites don't use the same trick every time. So, this really won't help you with those competitive coding sites, after all. Because next time you need to know a different programming or math trick. So, you see, you've spent all this time learning one trick, but it won't help you much in the long run, don't you agree?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Don't get me wrong... As much as I agree with the general idea of your crusade, imho you are taking it a bit too far sometimes. Solving crossword puzzles doesnt turn you into the next Shakespeare, thats true. One should not expect to improve ones english by training english crossword puzzles, also true. But that doesn't mean that crosswords puzzles are to be avoided at all cost.

Answer (score 0):

There is another:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

double fib(int n){
    double a = 0;
    double b = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        double temp = a;
        a = b;
        b += temp;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: This function works on C#, Python, and, probably, Ruby. If I missed an character, that's why I'm brazilian.